# How to get the "current" row value while using .iter_rows?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working on a access control system for my research group and I'm having a struggle while authenticating users with my database. 
I need to loop over a certain amount of rows (in an .xlsx file) and check if the value I have matches with any value on the column. If it does, the access will be granted. Otherwise, I need to print an error message.
I'd like to know if there's any smarter way on making this work, because as far as I checked openpyxl documentation it doesn't say anything that helps on extracting the value of the current row while iterating through rows.

Currently I have kind of a hardcoded way to make it work, using an aux variable (n) that is incremented on every row iterated through. Every iteration, 'n' is tested equal to the number of rows on the sheet. In case it's equal it means the loop has reached the end of the table and the user wasn't found.

```
# Checks if the UID was succesfully stored and is accessible
        for row in ws.iter_rows():
            if row[5].value == user.pin:
                print('Cadastro realizado com sucesso!')
                wb.close()
                del user
                break

            if n == ws.max_row:
                print('Usuário não autorizado')
                wb.close()
                gpio.output(10, gpio.LOW)
                del user
                n = 0
            n = n + 1
```

I was looking for some alternative like `row.row` or `row.value` that returns me the row I currently am while iterating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ws.iter_rows()` returns an iterable, you can use Python's built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to get an index as you iterate through your sheet. It works almost like your current solution behind the scenes, but makes the code cleaner and more readable.

Your code would look like this:

```
# Checks if the UID was succesfully stored and is accessible
    for idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows()):
        if row[5].value == user.pin:
            print('Cadastro realizado com sucesso!')
            wb.close()
            del user
            break

        if idx + 1 == ws.max_row:
            print('Usuário não autorizado')
            wb.close()
            gpio.output(10, gpio.LOW)
            del user
```